# What is the convenient way to distribute configurations between hundreds of machines

Tags: automation

we run a daemon in all of our machines, however we have a demand that we need to feed different machines with different configurations. 
What we need is like this:

1. When some one reconfigure some thing in the front end, we need to generate new configuration and send these new configurations to the specified machine.
2. Besides, we should also need to execute commands, like restart after configuration distributed.
3. we should have a way to check whether the configuration in the specified machine is the newest one, i.e. whether the configuration distribution executed in the first phrase succeeds or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep separate the generation of the new configs from the actual deployment.

I'd have a centralized daemon keeping track of the frontend changes and updating the configs and the necessary machine/config mapping in a central, well/known location. In a simpler form it could also be an on-demand manually executed process.

Your existing daemon would be modified to periodically check if the particular config for its own machine is changed and, if so, apply the change, perform the necessary deployment cmds and maybe even report back into the central location its own progress and results for the centralized daemon's overall status reporting. This keep this daemon code simpler (free from the machine/config mapping logic) and thus more reliable.